# Creating two identical entities on Fiware Orion

Tags: iot, fiware, fiware-orion

If I create two identical entities on Fiware Orion: same *name*, same *id* and same *attributes*, what is the behaviour of the system?. Does it do just an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orion will not let you to create two entities with the same id and type in the same service path. If you try to do that you will get an error like this one:

```
{
    "error": "Unprocessable",
    "description": "Already Exists"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to care whether the entity is created or just updated you can use the batch operation

POST /v2/op/update

with action type 'REPLACE' see https://github.com/Fiware/dataModels/blob/master/Weather/WeatherObserved/harvest/portugal_weather_observed_harvest.py#L149

You may also use action type 'APPEND'. The only caveat of that approach is that if the entity contains old attributes, they will remain ...

What the API does not support is an UPSERT operation ... i.e. the /v2/op/update would only work if the entity already exists ...

Comment: "... i.e. the /v2/op/update would only work if the entity already exists ... " Not really. If actionType is APPEND, then it will create the entities (in the case they don't previously exist)

Comment: oh, you are right. Then, the only caveat of APPEND is that existing attributes already remain in the Entity and sometimes that is not what you want. It would be great to have a real UPSERT operation. Something to be added to the ETSI standard.

Comment: In some sense, POST /v2/op/update with APPEND play the role of an UPSERT operation, isn't it?